# How to load fonts for three.js text geometry

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a three.js text geometry (sorry I am very new to Javascript).

I tried using my own JSON font but that gave the same error as using the fonts that three.js uses in their examples. I saw someone do the `self = this` thingy.

```js
this.pageTitles = [];
const self = this;
const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', (font) => {

    self.pages.forEach((page) => {

        self.pageTitles.push(
            new THREE.TextGeometry( page, {
                font: font,
                    size: 80,
                    height: 1,
                    curveSegments: 12,
                    bevelEnabled: false
             })
        );

    });


});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval [as onLoad] (three.module.js?5a89:40134)
    at XMLHttpRequest.eval (three.module.js?5a89:34850)
```

Note that I am using VueJS and this code is in a separate js file that exports a class.

Also, how would I load a font that I downloaded from google fonts and converted to .json format?

Comment: We recently had a similar issue in the three.js forum here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/uncaught-error-three-objloader-unexpected-line-doctype-html/8604

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for you comment, I put the json font into the `public` folder, which appears as `static/public` in sources when I look at developers tools. However the only thing in there is `favicon.ico` (the Vue icon), which when opened shows my `index.html` code (which is also in `public` in my project files). I am still getting the same error message. I'm so sorry for being so stupid 

Comment: Can you share your code as a github repo (similar to the OP in the three.js forum)? Ideally I can reproduce the error on my local machine and then look for a fix.

Comment: @Mugen87 You can find my project here: https://github.com/JoshidCoates/FractalPortfolio . The failing code is in `src/js/fractal.js`

Answer (score 1):

VueJs cannot parse path which is not from the dist folder.
Put helvetiker_bold.typeface.json into the dist folder.

```
const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( '/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', (font) => {
   ...//do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: I also had the exact same problem, but in React. I solved it by moving the font files to the `public` folder.